# Show that $S_x$ contains an interval

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

$X$ is Normed vector space, and $S_x={\{x\in X\space|\space\space\space||x||=1\}}$.
Prove that if exist $x,y\in X$ which are linearly independent such that $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$,
hence exist $u,v\in V$ such that $u\neq v$ and : $$ \{\lambda\cdot u+(1-\lambda)\cdot v\space|\space\lambda\in [0,1]\}\subseteq S_x $$

Thanks !